# How can I render four triangles in two corners of an SVG element?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am redesigning my website and i need to mentioned below. I have no experience in working with path and SVGs. Anyone help me with this.

I need two triangle path in top left corner of my section and two paths in bottom right corner of that same section.

As I am new to designing I need to correct this.

```css
.svgCorner {
  fill:  #ff0000;
  width: 7%;
}

.svgCornerBL{
    fill: #ff9933;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.svgCornerBR {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.svgCornerTL{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.svgCornerTR{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerTR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBL' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>

  <svg class='svgCorner svgCornerBR' id='svg4' viewBox='0 0 150 150'>               
    <path id='path1' d='M0 150L150 150L0 0'/>
  </svg>
```

Comment: You should make a quick image sketch and post it here so people know what you mean by triangles in corners.

Comment: You can run code snippet in my post.

Comment: Can you please add an image or at least a link to an image with the desired result?

Comment: Do you own Illustrator or Sketch by any chance ?

Comment: We can run the snippet and see what that looks like, but we can't tell what you want it to look like from what you have said. Can you tell us more about what you want it to look like?

Comment: @Ted I am new to stackoverflow Just created my account today. I cant embed image. In the above mentioned code it has four triangles in four corners. What i need is two triangles on top left corner and two triangles on top right corners. Help me with placing triangles i can position it by self.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for your hint I got it.

Comment: @BELCITTAESTHER Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Question solved.

Step 1:
  Created the shapes using illustrator and exported it as .SVG Files.

Step 2: 
  Placed the top SVG images code after 
  And placed the bottom SVG images code before

Step 3:
  Positioned it using simple CSS given Below.

```css
#top
{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
   
#bottom
{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Top left Corner -->
<img src="../svg/top.svg" id="top">
<img src="../svg/bottom.svg" id="top">

<!-- Bottom Right Corner -->
<img src="../svg/top1.svg" id="bottom">
<img src="../svg/bottom1.svg" id="bottom">
```